# Is "vampiric" a legitimate word?

Tags: word-choice

Writing a short story and the word 'vampiric' found its way on the screen, describing a medical blood-taking device. Word [of course] pitched a fit and I can... sort of... find some evidence that it is a 'real' word, but I'm not sure if it is indeed legitimate enough to use.

Comment: It's a real word. Try "vamperial," though, see if Word crashes altogether.

Comment: @Ricky "Vamperial" would be an entertaining portmanteau for a bloodsucking emperor, though...

Comment: @LaurenIpsum: Not merely entertaining, but stylish as well.

Comment: There are not illegitimate words.  Only illegitimate authors who make up bad words.  :) Like that shakespeare dude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, "vampiric" is a legitimate word.

If you don't own a dictionary, you can visit [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/vampiric) to research words and usage.

Comment: I did that but as I said -   the information was vague to that usage specifically.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. It looks like you're asking if it's a real word (it is) and whether it's legitimate enough to use (it is). If you're asking whether it can be used to describe a medical device, I imagine readers will understand what you mean by it in that context.

Comment: no worries - my question may have been equally vague :)

Answer (score 2):

In English, all words are legitimate. The only criteria is acceptance. French is a different matter all together. But, who cares about French?